# How can I sketch the level curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2-1)(2x+y-1)$.

Then how can I sketch the level curves of $f(x,y)$?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Do you have any thoughts on the problem? It will make our job easier and more likely to answer you.

Comment: Are you looking for curves defined by $f(x,y)=z$, for any given $z$, or to the specific case $z=0$, that is $f(x,y)=0$? The latter is almost trivial (union of the unit circle and a line), while the former is less obvious.

Answer (score 2):

According to the definition of [level curves](http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/2934/cal123.pdf), if we are given a function of two variables $z=f(x, y)$,the cross-section between the surface and a horizontal plane is called a *level curve* or a
*contour curve*. Thus, level curves have algebraic equations of the form:
$$f(x, y) =k$$
for **all possible values of** $k$. Now let's do this goal by using a mathematical software like Mathematica or Maple. I did it by Maple 16 for you:

[image]

Comment: the level curves should be in the plane?

Comment: @AtahualpaInca: If we assume that $z$ is the same as $f(x,y)$, so they are some surfaces as you noted in `3d`.

Comment: I still think they should live in the plane

Comment: @AtahualpaInca: I got what you mean. Let me correct it accordingly to be out of $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: Thank you, But I was wondering I could get those level sets without using computer. Just by hand. When k=0, it is easy. but other cases such as k=-1, 1, 2 etc.... that's my original question..

Comment: @math2357: Yes, it would be hard without a machine. If this post doesn't satisfy you, tell me to remove it. Indeed, without a software, sketching these curves, seems very difficult. Sorry if I could't help u.

Comment: no, it helps to me. you helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. The level curves of $f$ is the set 
$$ \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : f(x,y) = K, K \in \mathbb{R} \}$$. So, in order to find the level curves of your function, just set it equal to a constant K, and try different values of $K$. For instance

$$f(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2 -1)(2x + y -1) = K$$

Now, test values foe $K$, say $K=-1,-2,0,1,2,3$, and graph it in each different scenario.

Comment: I know, but can I compute this without computer? For example, when K=0, it is easy to get the curve. But K=1, K=2, or K=-1, then it seems very hard to figure out the whole level curves...

Comment: look at B.S. Answer.

Comment: @ILoveMath What if I don't have the formula for the function, but I have formulas for the components of its gradient vector field instead? Is there a way to get back the original function from its gradient?